# iOS: Handling interactive notifications when app is not running in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am trying to implement interactive local notifications for my app, and in particular via implementing this method:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification withResponseInfo:(NSDictionary *)responseInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

The method works fine except if the user kills the app and then receives an interactive local notification. In that case **there is no indication that the local notification action (button click) was received**.

I am looking for help/advice on 2 fronts

(1) Is anyone able to confirm/deny that `handleActionWithIdentifier` is not called when the app is not running at all (i.e. not even in background mode). I went through the relevant programming guide and I noticed that much of the language talked about `foreground` and `background` mode without addressing the third possibility. However, I'm looking for something more solid than 'it doesn't work for me' to put this to rest. Is there anything in the docs that says these should or should not work after the app is killed?

(2) How can I log in the Xcode console after I have killed my app? Every time I try this, I notice that when I relaunch the app I no longer have logging. This is important because I need to prove one way or another whether I receive interactive notification messages from user clicks after the user has killed the app.

I would appreciate any and all advice on this matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is terminated then when it gets launched via the notification then didFinishLaunchingWithOptions gets called with a key of UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey. The value of this key is an NSDictionary containing the payload of the local notification

You can't log in the Xcode console from the app if the app isn't running of course. But if you run the app not via Xcode you can watch the output by going to Window|Devices then selecting your attached device.
If you are relaunching the app via Xcode and logging isn't there this is probably a bug in Xcode, I've noticed recent versions of Xcode is having problems displaying logging. If this happens try the Devices output.

Comment: thanks for this helpful info. I'm embarassed to admit I can't figure out how to see my NSLog statements running on my iPhone not via Xcode. What do you  mean by Window/Devices? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: In Xcode's Window menu, select Devices, then the connected iPhone's name should appear on the left hand side (along with the Mac and list of simulators). When you click the the iPhone device Xcode displays device information and a device log console appears at the bottom. If you can't see it see if there is a disclose tab at the bottom of the screen (the disclose tab is a tiny upward pointing arrow in a tiny box).

Comment: I did try what you recommended, but all I am seeing listed on my device are crash logs. I am trying to see NSLog type statements...

Comment: If your app is running, and logging stuff it should appear. It will look like "May 13 11:48:40 iPhone NameOfApp[324] <Warning>: log message here". If not then I don't know why, try quitting and re-launching Xcode.